# RGB to Hex Conversion: returns more than 6 char hex string

Tags: ios, swift, uicolor

I am using the following to convert hex to rgb and rgb to hex.

```
extension UIColor {
    convenience init(hex: String) {
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hex)
        scanner.scanLocation = 0

        var rgbValue: UInt64 = 0

        scanner.scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)

        let r = (rgbValue & 0xff0000) >> 16
        let g = (rgbValue & 0xff00) >> 8
        let b = rgbValue & 0xff

        self.init(
            red: CGFloat(r) / 0xff,
            green: CGFloat(g) / 0xff,
            blue: CGFloat(b) / 0xff, alpha: 1
        )
    }

    func toHexString() -> String {
        var r: CGFloat = 0
        var g: CGFloat = 0
        var b: CGFloat = 0
        var a: CGFloat = 0
        self.getRed(&r, green: &g, blue: &b, alpha: &a)

        return String(format: "%02X%02X%02X", Int(r * 255), Int(g * 255), Int(b * 255))
    }
}
```

`UIColor init(hex:String)` works fine but when I try to get hex from `UIColor` it always returns a string with more than 6 characters like "D7FFFFFFFFE9". Can anyone point out the problem in the code?

Comment: Verify if any of `r`, `g`, or `b` is greater than 1.0 in your `toHexString` method.

Comment: What did the debugger tell you when you stepped through each line and checked all intermediate results? I don't know what it is, but come on this should be very easy to find.

Comment: Have a look here [SwiftHEXColors](https://github.com/thii/SwiftHEXColors/blob/master/Sources/SwiftHEXColors.swift)

Comment: hi rmaddy : r , g, or b is less than or equals to 1.

Comment: @Uma_Shanker_Tiwari can you show the color you are trying to change to hexString and get the same result as in the question

Comment: According to the [documentation of `getRed(_:green:blue:alpha:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicolor/1621919-getred), r, g, b can take any value (including negative) since iOS 10. If any of r, g, b is negative, the result can be as shown in the question.

Comment: Please print a log of "r","g","b" and also change your format to this.. "%02X.%02X.%02X" so you can see which value is wrong

Comment: some times, I can see r, g,b is negative. If this is the problem, can you suggested how to fix this.

Comment: Make sure you check the return value of the `getRed:green:blue:alpha:` method. If it returns `false`, then it didn't work and the values are not valid.